# Style guide for documentation in HTML urges to use spaces in <code>...</code>

Tags: html

In the style guide for the maintenance of a bulky documentation of an existing system using HTML which I has to maintain for a client, I found, that text given in a code-tag should be enclosed with spaces like:

`..., the element<code> STATE </code>matches datatype ...`

In most cases the whole text is enclosed in `<p>` tags:

`<p>..., the element<code> STATE </code>matches datatype ...</p>`

Does anyone has an idea why I should write `<code> STATE </code>` with no place before and afterwards?

One explanation could be that rendering the HTML leads to "better" (i. e. same / bigger width, ...) constant spaces between normal text and the code (the space in code-tag seems to be "bigger"). Is that approach meaningful? Or are there arguments against this rule so I could convince the program director to kick-out this rule?

Comment: No reason to do that, the spaces are not part of the code and so should be outside the <code> tags. Maybe ask why they want to make it like this, because there's no logical reason.

Comment: That's my opinion too, but I'm not an expert in HTML.

Comment: The problem is depending of the display of an element, spaces should be not properly trimmed, so you'll obtain undesired spaces on the layout. There's no reason for this, but the opinion of the boss. I had a designer boss in the past that he wants all CSS writing on a single line (each selector and its properties all in one line). He argues that he hates multiline CSS. I argue him that's unreadable and unmaintenable. He tells me that doesn't matter, he hates it and he don't want to see multiline CSS on his project. I shut up and wrote poor quality CSS. Sometimes we need to do our bosses want.

Comment: Hola Marcos, you're right. A strong argument especially in my case because a client even overrules a boss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a way of enforcing a style without, for whatever reason, using CSS.

There's no reason to do this other than to conform to somebody's preference (your boss or a client, presumably, in this case).

To back this up, the HTML specification itself uses examples of `<code>` elements wrapped within `<p>` elements which **do not** follow this format:

> ### Example 104
>
> The following example shows how the element can be used in a paragraph to mark up element names and computer code, including punctuation.
>
> ```
> <p>The <code>code</code> element represents a fragment of computer code.</p>
> ```
>
> — [Example 104 within the HTML5.1 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/textlevel-semantics.html#the-code-element)

Comment: Giving an example is a kick on the ass of the boss. Well found!